# How to make container fix positioned even after keyboard is displayed

Tags: flutter

I've been playing with this for some time and can not get this working. Basically I've got bottom navigation bar and I want at the top of the bottom navigation bar fixed positioned container which stay there even if the keyboard is displayed. So far no matter what I tried the container ends up at the top of the keyboard when the keyboard is called.  Here is my code where I ended up so far. Basically my last hope was to wrap it in Stack widget but that didn't work.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {   static const String id = '/app';   final FirebaseUser user;   HomeScreen({this.user});

  @override   _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState(); }

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {   int _currentIndex
= 0;   final List<Widget> _children = [Screen1(), Screen2()];

  void bottomTabHandler(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: bottomTabHandler,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.receipt),
            title: Text('Option1'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.receipt),
            title: Text('Option2'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('Option3')),
        ],
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('XXX'),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      endDrawer: AppbarDrawer(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _children[_currentIndex],
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: 250,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
     );
    }    
}
```

I've got simple TextField at screen1 and this is what I get

[image][image]

Comment: Could please clarify if it's the container that you want to not be overlapped by the keyboard, or your BottomNavigationBar ?

Comment: BottomNavigationBar is always behind keyboard which is what I want. The container though is what I want to be also behind the keyboard fixed at the top of the BottomNavigationBar but is always at the top of the keyboard now

Comment: Please check the answer I've written below and check if it does what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make sure the Widgets don't get adjusted when the keyboard appears, you can use the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property of the `Scaffold`:

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: Stack(
  ...
```